# Bash preserve tab on large text

Tags: bash, echo

I have the following echo string:

```
echo "Title"
echo -e "\t Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
```

My output is:

```
> [mymachine ~]$ example.sh
> Title
>        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
> industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
> since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and 
> scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
```

As you can see in this example the text string is too large and console put it in four lines but only the first one preserve tab.

I'm looking for this output:

```
> [mymachine ~]$ example.sh
> Title
>        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
>        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
>        ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
>        and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
```

Is there any way to make large text string preserve tab for each line on console?

Comment: Have you tried using `cat` rather than `echo`? You can't set up the line length but you can directly write what is going to be shown: `cat <<EOT
       your text with multiple lines and spaces EOT`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for something like `fmt`:

```
echo "Title"
printf "\tLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.\n" \
| fmt
```

Surprisingly, gnu fmt (version 8.25) does not honor $COLUMNS, so you may want to use:

```
fmt -w ${COLUMNS:-80}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works as excepted.